# Bootstrap button dropdown with input text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap. I am creating a horizontal form in which I require a button dropdown to be placed in the left and an input text in the right. I have written the code but for some reason the button dropdown is coming in the right and the input text is coming in the left. Below is the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  Categories <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
     <li class="divider"></li>
     <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-offset col-sm-10">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Debate Name">
</div>
```

What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the btn-group div doesn't have a column to sit inside.  Make this change:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="col-sm-2"> <!--Wrap this button group in a col -->
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Categories <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /col-sm-2 -->
    <div class="col-sm-10"> <!--Offsets work like cols they require a value for how many cols to offset -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Debate Name">
    </div>
</form>
```

When using Bootstrap 'out of the box,' the combination of all of your col values should add up to 12.  That includes any offsets.  If they add up to more than 12, the last col will wrap.  If less than 12, and there will be a gap.  Since cols have float left applied to them, in your case, the div with the col-sm-10 was floating left and taking up 10 grid columns, allowing for 2 to be empty.  Because there was nothing to clear the float, the btn-group div floated next to it.

Also, just to note, if you want to use offsets, they behave like columns and take up a specific number of grid columns.  That means you need to tell them how many columns like this: `.col-md-offset-*` replacing the * with a number.  If you wanted to use an offset in your example you could change the above to something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-9  col-sm-offset-1"> <!--2 grid cols for the button group + 9 + 1 for the input = 12 -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Debate Name">
</div>
```

Finally, you should note that the -sm- portion of the classes means that your columns will behave like this for all screens above 767px in wide, below that, the button will be on top of the input.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it worked. Also thanks for the extra tip. I didnt knew the concept of 12 in the columns.

Comment: Just one thing, it is now on the left side but it is not proper aligned with all the other left hand side elements.

Comment: Happy to help try and diagnose the problem, but I'm not sure I know what it can be without seeing more of the code.  Can you create a fiddle, bootply or post the rest of your code?

Comment: Thanks jme11, but I figured it out. Thanks for the help